# Get metadata from MP3 HTTP stream

Tags: swift, http, mp3, avplayer

I want to get the Metadata from a MP3 HTTP stream. The stream is played with AVPlayer.

I've tried it with the AVPlayerItemMetadataCollector but it returns nil.

The alternative is to get the specific part on the website of the stream where the current title is displayed.

Here is my player code:

```
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(string: "stream.p4.no/p5trondheim_mp3_hq")!)
player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
player.rate = 1.0;
player.play()
```

What can I do?

Comment: Can you add a little more example code to your question?

Comment: Here’s my player code

Comment: let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(string: "http://stream.p4.no/p5trondheim_mp3_hq")!)
player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
player.rate = 1.0;
player.play()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can observe timedMetadata on your AVPlayerItem :

```
{
  ...
  // Add observer
  playerItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "timedMetadata", options: .new, context: nil)
  ...
}

// Observe
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
  guard keyPath == "timedMetadata" else { return }
  guard let meta = playerItem.timedMetadata else { return }
  for metadata in meta {
    if let songName = metadata.value(forKey: "value") as? String {
      print("song name is '\(songName)'")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. It worked so far but how can I filter specific parts from the String? It returns: song name is '{"artist":"Alan Walker feat. Gavin James","duration":179041,"imageUrl":"http://trondheim.p5.no/mmo/MusicLibrary/14c1b7c2-92e4-4a7e-be70-90ca7112f2c5.jpg","MetaContentId":9314462,"musicId":"1720-03","title":"Tired","type":"music","url":"http://trondheim.p5.no/musikk/sang/1720-03"}'